# Issuing with making a post request with php curl

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm trying to make a post request with php using curl however the json is not getting delivered to the REST API. Here is my code. In the webservice all I get is null value. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

```
    $email_json_data = json_encode($email_data);

    $header[] = "Content-type: application/json";

    $ch = curl_init($api_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $email_json_data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    return $response;
```

**Webservice code:**

```
$email_json_data = $this->post('email_json_data');
$email_data = json_decode($email_json_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Check [PHP: curl_errno](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php)

There's probably a problem connecting to the server, and it's probably in one of your `$header`. To find out more, you need to show (in production, LOG it) the curl error.

**In the future, please try to include a complete code sample, rather than just snippets**

#### Code added from [PHP: curl_strerror](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-strerror.php)

```
class CurlAdapter
{ 
    private $api_url = 'www.somewhere.com/api/server.php';

    private $error = "";

    private function jsonPost($data)
    {
        // init curl
        $ch = curl_init($this->api_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // curl header
        $header[] = "Content-type: application/json";
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

        // build post data
        $post_data = json_encode($data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

        // execute
        if (empty($response = curl_exec($ch)) {
            // Check for errors and display the error message
            if($errno = curl_errno($ch)) {
                $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
                $this->error = "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}";
                // @todo log curl error
            }    
        }

        // Close the handle
        curl_close($ch);

        return $response;
    }

    public function post( mixed $data ) 
    {  
        if (empty($this->jsonPost($data))) {
            return $this->error;
        }

        return $response;
    }    
}

$ca = new CurlAdapter();

echo $ca->post(['data' => 'testdata']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way to make this work.

Replaced `$email_json_data = $this->post('email_json_data');`

with `$email_json_data = file_get_contents("php://input");`